# Calcular uma string em Python

Tags: python, string, matemática

Eu gostaria de fazer um cálculo de uma string que eu recebo, por exemplo:

```
var = '1+2'
```

Queria transformar essa string em uma conta, para retornar 3 para a variável `var` e não '1+2', mas isso não seria apenas somado, teria subtração, multiplicação e divisão, ainda poderá ter uma operação mista, ex: `var = '2*4+1'` e etc... Acho que vocês já entenderam...

O problema é que eu recebo essa conta como string

Tentei usar o `int(var)`, mas não da certo teria alguma função tipo `calc(var)`?

Comment: Acredito que o que você precisa é interpretar e processar uma expressão matemática contida dentro de uma string, encontrei uma resposta para o que você precisa neste [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que vais ter cuidado com os inputs que recebes a maneira mais simples é:

```
var = '1+2'
print(eval(var)) # 3

var = '5*3'
print(eval(var)) # 15
```

Como o cologa @jsbueno disse e bem, podes usar ast.literal_eval, que acaba por ser mais seguro se não tiveres controlo sobre os inputs que entram para dentro da função `eval()`:

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval('4+10')) # 14
```

Comment: Existe a opção de `ast.literal_eval` que só permite a aniulação de tipos primitivos do Python, sem executar código arbitrário.